# Oracle SQL Query 2

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies, I hope I have put this in the right place, but I just have a couple of questions re my database which I cannot figure out why my queries aren't working.

My Database Relation Schema is as follows:

```
DEPARTMENT(deptnum, descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)
ACADEMIC(acnum, deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)
PAPER(panum, d.)
AUTHOR(panum*, acnum*)
FIELD(fieldnum, id, title)
INTEREST(fieldnum*, acnum*, descrip)
```

1) I need to find if there are any more academics who have written less than 20 papers. I need to list the acnum, title, famname, givename and number of papers they have written. See my attempt below:

```
SELECT a.acnum, a.title, a.famname, a.givename, count(p.panum)
FROM ACADEMIC a 
   INNER JOIN PAPER p 
   INNER JOIN AUTHOR au ON a.acnum = au.acnum and au.panum = p.panum 
GROUP BY a.ACNUM, a.title, a.famname, a.givename 
HAVING COUNT(p.panum) < 20;
```

2) I also need to find the departments with the largest number of academics and print their deptnum, deptname and instname, but im getting a syntax error. See my attempt:

```
SELECT deptnum, deptname, instname, count(acnum) 
FROM department, academic, 
WHERE academic.deptnum = department.deptnum 
GROUP BY deptnum 
HAVING MAX(count(acnum));
```

Comment: If I understand your schema correctly, there should be no duplicates in the `author` table (a specific academic shouldn't be shown as the author of a specific paper more than once). If so, in the first query you only need one join, between `academic` and `author` - you don't need to join to the `paper` table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a pair `(panum, acnum)` doesn't appear in `author` more than once (there are no duplicates in that table), you don't need to join to `paper` in the first query. This should suffice:

```
SELECT a.acnum, a.title, a.famname, a.givename, count(au.panum) as ct
FROM ACADEMIC a 
   INNER JOIN AUTHOR au ON a.acnum = au.acnum
GROUP BY a.ACNUM, a.title, a.famname, a.givename 
HAVING COUNT(au.panum) < 20;
```

The error in your original attempt was the order of the `on` conditions; the first inner join must be followed IMMEDIATELY by its corresponding `on` condition, you can't leave it for later. However, as I just showed, you only need one join.

For the second query, you need to find the department(s) with the max number of academics first, using the `academic` table. Then you can join the result to the `department` table.

```
select d.deptnum, d.deptname, d.instname, m.ct
from   department d inner join
       ( select   deptnum, count(acnum) as ct
         from     academic
         group by deptnum
         having   count(acnum) = (select max(acnum) from academic group by deptnum)
       ) m
           on d.deptnum = m.deptnum
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your joins need to be in order that they load.

```
SELECT a.acnum, a.title, a.famname, a.givename, COUNT(p.panum)
FROM ACADEMIC a
INNER JOIN AUTHOR au ON a.acnum = au.acnum
INNER JOIN PAPER p ON au.panum = p.panum 
GROUP BY a.ACNUM, a.title, a.famname, a.givename 
HAVING COUNT(p.panum) < 20;
```

Use an `ORDER BY` to give you the top department.

```
SELECT d.deptnum, d.deptname, d.instname, COUNT(a.acnum) 
FROM department d
INNER JOIN academic a d.deptnum = a.deptnum
GROUP BY d.deptnum, d.deptname, d.instname
ORDER BY COUNT(a.acnum);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, im still however getting a syntax error: Missing keyword. Any ideas?

Comment: @B.Straat try now

Comment: The second query will still return all the departments, not just the one (or two or three...) with the largest number of academics.

Answer (score 0):

Are you need to eliminate duplicates or its

```
SELECT a.acnum, a.title, a.famname, a.givename, count(au.panum)
FROM ACADEMIC a 
JOIN AUTHOR au ON a.acnum = au.acnum 
GROUP BY a.ACNUM, a.title, a.famname, a.givename 
HAVING COUNT(au.panum) < 20;
```

and

```
SELECT deptnum, deptname, instname, count_ac
FROM (
    SELECT d.deptnum, d.deptname, d.instname, COUNT(a.acnum) as COUNT_AC 
    FROM department d
    JOIN academic a d.deptnum = a.deptnum
    GROUP BY d.deptnum, d.deptname, d.instname
    ORDER BY COUNT(a.acnum)
) WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```

or

```
SELECT deptnum, deptname, instname, count_ac
FROM (
    SELECT d.deptnum, d.deptname, d.instname, dense_rank() over (order by COUNT(a.acnum) desc) cur_rank, COUNT(a.acnum) as count_ac
    FROM department d
    JOIN academic a d.deptnum = a.deptnum
    GROUP BY d.deptnum, d.deptname, d.instname
) WHERE cur_rank = 1;
```

Comment: The second query will work, but it will miss "ties" (cases when there may be two or three departments tied for the largest number of academics).

Comment: Thank you for your point. I add code with dense_rank to fix it